# Accessing a key value pairs in a JsonResponse in Django Unit Testing

Tags: django, unit-testing

I want to access the data returned in the following jsonResponse object:

```
{"results": [[1, "Probability and Stochastic Processes", 9781118324561, "Roy D. Yates", "2014-01-01", "Wiley"], [2, "Interaction Design", 9781119020752, "Rogers Price", "2015-01-01", "John Wiley & Sons"], [3, "Microeconomics", 9780077501808, "Colander", "2013-01-01", "McGraw Hill"], [4, "jfalksdjf", 123123, "test", "1990-01-01", "Penguin"]]}
```

I am running into trouble however and I have tried many things

```
def test_noIDGiven(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('allTextbooks')) #returns the json array above
    #check that there are three textbooks in the response
    #print(response.content['results'][0][0]) - this didnt work
    self.assertEquals(response.content[0][0], 1) #basically want to access the id of the first object and make sure it is 1
```

Any help on how the best way to go about accessing the key value pairs of this object would be nice. thanks in advance

More information:
- when i reverse 'allTextbooks' the api call returns this:

```
results = list(Textbook.objects.values_list())
return JsonResponse({'results': results})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must try converting your response to dictionary first,

```
import json
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
id_list = []
```

Now,

```
for k,v in response_dict:
    for i in v:
        id_list.append(i[0])
```

id_list is your list of all the id's.

Comment: .text isnt an attribute of the response and if i try response.content it get a "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'" error

Answer (score 9):

From Django 2.0, you can access JSON response directly.

```
 self.assertEqual(response.json()['results'][0][0], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with response['results'][0][0]?

And if you want to access easily to each item in the response, you can try with this:

```
for item in response['results']:
    print item[0]
```

Comment: yes i did try response['results'][0][0] and i got a key error at 'results'

Comment: then What type of object do you have in "response = self.client.get(reverse('allTextbooks'))" ? Because if you get that error it's not a json

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the response content is just bytes, so you have to decode that as UTF-8 (or whatever), then parse it as JSON into a dict, like so:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('allTextbooks'))
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
self.assertEqual(response['Content-Type'], 'application/json')
j = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
self.assertEqual(j['results'][0][0], 1)
```

I've included a couple extra assertions to verify that the response is successful and flagged as JSON, but those are optional.

Comment: This worked for me

j = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')